# Just installed Ubuntu 14.04. Internet connection goes amazingly fast, then goes very slow

Tags: 14.04, wireless, internet, connection

My wireless internet connection goes extremely fast which I love, but then it slows down a lot. I just installed Ubuntu, and aside from the slow-down I love everything about it. Just I am having a hard time finding a fix to this problem. My laptop is an HP by the way.

Thanks for reading and for the help.

Comment: Remmy, welcome to AskUbuntu, but I just wanted to let you know that not everyone is a native English speaker on this site.
So "having a good one" and "snail's pace" are to be avoided if you want to get a decent answer...  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently installed Ubuntu as well and faced the same problem. My wi-fi was quite fast at first, then it was pretty much dead. I tried the following solutions and they fixed the problem on my Lenovo laptop.

1. For Slow WiFi in Atheros Wireless Network Adaptors:

   `sudo -s`

   `echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf`
2. Disable 802.11n

   `sudo rmmod iwlwifi`

   `sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`

   If this doesn't work for you, forget about it, otherwise make it permanent:

   `sudo su`

   `echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

   `sudo service networking restart` (or reboot)
3. Disable IPv6 support

   `sudo su`

   `echo "#disable ipv6" >> /etc/sysctl.conf`

   `echo "net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf`

   `echo "net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf`

   `echo "net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf`

   `sudo service networking restart` (or reboot)
4. Ditch default network manager and embrace wicd

   `sudo apt-get install wicd`

[<sub>Source</sub>](http://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/)

Also, there is already a similar question asked by another HP user. Check this solution as well.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2175345

Comment: Dude wow! Thanks a ton! I tried all of the solutions in the first link, but none were that relevant to me. I then did the second link and it worked! THANKS A TON! I had been trying to figure it out all night. I love Ubuntu!

Comment: Steven, don't just post a link to an external web site that might completely dissapear, but copy-paste the solution into AskUbuntu and refer to the site afterwards as a source.  I helped you for the first one (might take a while to appear as even moderators are moderated)  ;-)